# How to find a specific file between a date range in windows server 2012,

Tags: windows, search

How to find a specific file between a date range in windows server 2012, I want to try to found a file modified before 3 months

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, using `forfiles`:

```
forfiles /D +22/03/2020 /C "cmd /c echo @fname"
```